# Parse Json object

Tags: json

I have a following Json object:

```
data = [{"$id":"1","ID":2,"Name":"Exceptional trip to ZG"}]
```

I need to parse it so I can display individual attributes on my webpage.

I tried using this code:

```
var lang = '';
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
      $.each(obj, function() {
      lang += this['ID'] + "<br/>";
  });
  $("#mybox1").html(lang);
```

but it doesn't work as $.parseJSON expects Json string like this one:

`[{"$id":"1","ID":2,"Name":"Exceptional trip to ZG"}]` - same only with quotation marks around it. This code works perfectly with Json string.

Comment: You don't need to parse it. It's already a JavaScript object.

Comment: Can you help me how to access individual attribute, for example to display just an ID?

Comment: What is `$`? jQuery?

Comment: Your code would work fine if you removed the call to `parseJSON` and simply looped over `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to parse? It's already a valid object. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjn39ahr/).

This will accomplish your task:

```
var data = [{
  "$id": "1",
  "ID": 2,
  "Name": "Exceptional trip to ZG"
}];

var lang = '';
$.each(data, function () {
lang += this['ID'] + "<br/>";
});

$("#mybox1").val(lang);
```

Comment: This works with the variable data if i declare it in code like this. However, it doesn't work when i get data from a server via $.ajax method.

Comment: Your var data is all we have to go on. What's the data coming back from the server?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/4jyki1 this is the complete code and it doesn't work even though datam is completely same as "var data" from your code which works perfectly.

Comment: I can't verify/test since it's only a screenshot, but have you tried attaching the .done to the actual ajax request instead of calling it from your 'request' variable? I'd also suggest running your DOM manipulation inside the '.done' promise. I can't check but I bet 'datam' is out of scope in your .each loop.